# Oracle - Trying to execute a procedure using perl

Tags: oracle

I am trying to execute a procedure using perl as under:

```
my @tabs = qw!ACTOR ADDRESS CATEGORY CITY COUNTRY CUSTOMER FILM INVENTORY LANGUAGE STAFF STORE!;
  for my $ts (@tabs){
     chomp $ts;
        my $csr = $ora->prepare(q{
           BEGIN
             update_cascade.on_table(:ts)
           END;
        });
$csr->bind_param(":ts", $ts);
$csr->execute;
}
```

Which results in following errors:

```
DBD::Oracle::st execute failed: ORA-06550: line 4, column 12:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the following:


   := . ( % ;
The symbol ";" was substituted for "END" to continue. (DBD ERROR: error possibly near <*> indicator at char 71 in '
           BEGIN
             update_cascade.on_table(:ts)
           <*>END;
        ') [for Statement "
           BEGIN
             update_cascade.on_table(:ts)
           END;
        " with ParamValues: :ts='ACTOR'] at sakila_update_cascade.pl line 18.
DBD::Oracle::st execute failed: ORA-06550: line 4, column 12:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the following:


   := . ( % ;
The symbol ";" was substituted for "END" to continue. (DBD ERROR: error possibly near <*> indicator at char 71 in '
           BEGIN
             update_cascade.on_table(:ts)
           <*>END;
        ') [for Statement "
           BEGIN
             update_cascade.on_table(:ts)
           END;
        " with ParamValues: :ts='ACTOR'] at sakila_update_cascade.pl line 18.
```

I can execute it within SQLPlus as under

```
exec update_cascade.on_table(:'ACTOR');
```

I tried with:

```
update_cascade.on_table('||:ts||')
```

It does not get executed and get this perl error:

> Can't bind unknown placeholder ':ts' (':ts') at sakila_mig.pl line 659.

The DBD::Oracle package sites an example as under:

```
my $test_num = 5;
  my $is_odd;

  $csr = $db->prepare(q{
  BEGIN
  PLSQL_EXAMPLE.PROC_IN_INOUT(:test_num, :is_odd);
  END;
  });
  $csr->bind_param(":test_num", $test_num);

  $csr->bind_param_inout(":is_odd", \$is_odd, 1);
  $csr->execute;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're simply missing a semicolon (;)

Try :

```
      BEGIN
        update_cascade.on_table(:ts);
      END;
```

The code looks ok !